# how to insert unique record using JMeter distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

I have set up Jmeter distributed testing with 1 master and 2 slaves.

During my test, I have added deviceId as a variable with MIN and MAX ranges. when I run the distributed test, the insert is successful in one slave machine and failed in another slave machine with 'E11000 duplicate key error collection'.

How can I set up the test so that when I run insert is successful in both the machines

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you really "define" this variable and where the "ranges" come from.

if `E` is a prefix and `11000` is a postfix it means that you can send only up to 100 000 "unique" entries.

So one of the solutions would be pre-generate the list of these entries and store it into CSV file like:

```
E00000 
E00001
...
E99999
```

then you can split the file into 2 parts and copy it to the slaves, the lines from the file can be read using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

If you need the ability to continue the test where you left off without re-using the data you can go for [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction/) instead.

Another possible option is checking whether the value is in the database before extracting using [JDBC Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) and generate a new one if current value exists already, however this option is not the best one.

And last but not the least, you can generate really unique values using [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) if the output format is appropriate